# Can I split open/divide a large MS SQL disk media set?

Tags: backup, sql-server-2005, tsql

MSSQL 2005
An old maintenance plan was backing up a database to a single disk based media set with append. It contains numerous full backups of about 2GB each. I now have a single media set  file almost 0.5TB in size.

Is it possible to easily split this media set into individual .bak files?

I have now changed our maintenance plan to backup to individual files rather than a single disk device. This makes file transfer more manageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.  All you can do is change the maintenance plan to use a different filename for each backup, then after a couple of days delete the stupidly large file.

Comment: +1 For telling me what I didn't want to hear! Sadly, as a business, we have to be in a position to roll back to a point in time in our data. Our internal application does not audit changes to the database (it would have if I had written it!). I will need to store this large file for a number of years. I do accept this is likely the one and only answer, but I'll leave this open for a short while.

Comment: I'd compress the file (it'll compress pretty well) and burn it to a couple of DVDs just to be safe so that you don't have to worry about it.